# Reduce formula using Euler's?

Tags: trigonometry, signal-processing, euler-product

I am performing a self-study, and I am lost as to a derivation that has taken place.

I basically started with this equation:

$$
\Upsilon(\phi) = e^{-j\frac{N-1}{2}\phi} \ \Big[ \frac{1 - e^{j N \phi}}{1 - e^{j \phi}} \Big]
$$

Somehow, the result is that this above equation can be reduced to this:

$$
\Upsilon(\phi) = \frac{\sin(\frac{N \phi}{2})}{\sin(\frac{\phi}{2})}
$$

I am at a loss as to how this was accomplished.

---

**What I have tried:** I understand and have tried to use euler's formulas, $\sin(x) = \frac{e^{j \ x} - e^{-j x}}{2 \ j}$, etc, but I was only able to recover the numerator of the first equation. I am not sure really if there is a simpler way that I am simply not getting. Would appreciate any insight. I also tried expanding by multiplying by the conjugate of the denominator, but still no luck... Thanks.

Comment: Write $$e^{-j\frac{N-1}{2}\phi} =\frac{e^{-j\frac{N}{2}\phi}}{e^{-j\frac{1}{2}\phi}}$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Let me try this.

Comment: @DanielFischer It worked. I am very, very angry at myself for not seeing that. ><

Comment: Stop that. You will, if you are normal, so often overlook something simple that you'd be perpetually very, very angry at yourself. Just say d'oh and move on.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, wise words!

Comment: Note this is also the $N$-th Dirichlet Kernel
$$\Upsilon(\phi) = D_N(\phi) = \sum_{n=1}^N e^{in\phi}$$
And on the right is it's closed form ;-)

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**
Use this equality
$$1-e^{jx}=e^{jx/2}(e^{-jx/2}-e^{jx/2})=-2j\sin(x/2)e^{jx/2}$$

Comment: Thanks, I used Daniel's suggestion.

Comment: All the roads lead to Rome:). You're welcome

Comment: Very true! :-)   .

Comment: This post is Spacey, Spicy and delicious. :=)

Answer (score 3):

$$e^{-j\frac{N-1}{2}\phi}=e^{-j\frac{N}{2}\phi}e^{j\frac{1}{2}\phi}$$

Now take this and apply it to the full equation:

$$\Upsilon(\phi) = e^{-j\frac{N-1}{2}\phi} \left[ \frac{1 - e^{j N \phi}}{1 - e^{j \phi}} \right]$$

$$\Upsilon(\phi)=e^{-j\frac{N}{2}\phi}\left[ \frac{(1 - e^{j N \phi})}{e^{-j\frac{1}{2}\phi} - e^{j \frac{1}{2}\phi}} \right]$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you, I used @Daniel's suggestion.